# How to show and hide div elements based on the selection of radio buttons in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to `show` and `hide` a div based on a `radio` button.
I have these codes, and I could not find anywhere is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("value") == "student") {
                    $(".studentq").show();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <label name="Q2">I am a:</label>
    <input type="radio" name="A2" value="student">Student
    <input type="radio" name="A2" value="parent">Parent

    <div class="studentq">

        <label name="Q3">If Student, High School Graduation Year:</label>
        <select name="A3">
            <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
            <option value=<?php echo $beforeyear2;?>>
                <?php echo $beforeyear2;?>
            </option>
            <option value=<?php echo $beforeyear1;?>>
                <?php echo $beforeyear1;?>
            </option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
        </select>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I load the page, while the `div class = "studentq"` should not show since the value is empty,  it still shows, and clicking on the radio buttons does not work.

Any one could help?

Thanks a lot!

Thank you chayasan!

I changed it like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".studentq").hide();
                $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
                    if ($(this).attr("value") == "student") {
                        $(".studentq").show();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <label name = "Q2" >I am a:</label>
    <input type = "radio" name = "A2" value = "student" >Student
    <input type = "radio" name = "A2" value = "parent" >Parent

    <div class ="studentq">

    <label name = "Q3" >If Student, High School Graduation Year:</label>
    <select name = "A3" >
    <option disabled selected> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option value ="1">2014</option>
    <option value ="2">2015</option>
    <option value ="Other" >Other</option>
    </select>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It  works now!!!

Answer (score 2):

You should hide the `.studentq` element when the page loads.

```js
$(".studentq").hide();
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("value") == "student") {
    $(".studentq").show();
  } else {
    $(".studentq").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label name="Q2">I am a:</label>
<input type="radio" name="A2" value="student">Student
<input type="radio" name="A2" value="parent">Parent

<div class="studentq">

  <label name="Q3">If Student, High School Graduation Year:</label>
  <select name="A3">
    <option disabled selected>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply! Mine still does not work....did I miss anything? I did miss the line: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> before

Comment: I think what you have to do is, put the `$(".studentq").hide();` line inside your `document.ready` function. (At the top)

Comment: Can you show us the code using a fiddle? or else, can you edit the question with the new change so I can take a look?

Comment: Sure. Please wait for a while!

Comment: @user5004724 I can see the edited question now. Haven't you included jquery (I see it as a commented out line)? You can do it by inserting `<script src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>` line between your `<head>` tags.

Comment: Yes yes it is the problem! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following:

```
// selecting the <input> elements of type=radio,
// and binding the anonymous function to handle
// the change event:
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {

  // caching the reference to the changed <input>:
  var check = this;

  // selecting the elements with the class of
  // 'parentOrStudent' and hiding them all;
  // using the filter() method:
  $('.parentOrStudent').hide().filter(function() {

    // to keep only those elements for whom the following is true,
    // the checkbox is checked and the .parentOrStudent element
    // contains the value ('parent' or 'student') in its classList:
    return check.checked && this.classList.contains(check.value);

  // we show only those elements retained in the collection:
  }).show();

// we then trigger the change event to fire the function
// on page load:
}).change();
```

```js
$('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
  var check = this;
  $('.parentOrStudent').hide().filter(function() {
    return check.checked && this.classList.contains(check.value);
  }).show();
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>I am a:</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="A2" value="student" />Student</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="A2" value="parent" />Parent</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset class="parentOrStudent student">

  <legend>If Student, High School Graduation Year:</legend>
  <select id="A3">
    <option disabled selected>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

</fieldset>


<fieldset class="parentOrStudent parent">

  <legend>If parent, some other pertinent question:</legend>
  <select id="A4">
    <option disabled selected>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

</fieldset>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/udm0uvod/), for experimentation.

Incidentally, to use plain JavaScript, the following would suit (although I've amended the `<input>` elements' HTML to use a custom `data-refersto` attribute to specify to which elements the `<input>` elements should work on:

```
// creating a named function to handle the events:
function toggleElements() {

  // caching the changed <input> element:
  var check = this,

  // caching the elements that should be affected, by
  // concatenating a '.' with the value held in the 
  // changed-element's 'data-refersto' attribute:
    refersTo = document.querySelectorAll('.' + check.dataset.refersto);

  // if we retrieved any elements in the 'refersTo' variable:
  if (refersTo && refersTo.length) {

    // we use Array.prototype.forEach() to iterate over
    // the collection, and use Function.prototype.call()
    // to use the Array-like collection (refersTo) with
    // an Array method:
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(refersTo, function(node) {

      // if the changed element is checked, and
      // the current refersTo node (here referred to
      // as 'node') contains a class equal to the value
      // of the changed element:
      if (check.checked && node.classList.contains(check.value)) {

        // we set the display to 'block' (to show):
        node.style.display = 'block';
      } else {

        // otherwise we set the display to 'none' (to hide):
        node.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }
}

// we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve all <input>
// elements of type=radio with a 'date-refersto' attribute:   
var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][data-refersto]'),

// creating a new Event, in order that we can trigger the
// 'change' event:
  changeEvent = new Event('change');

// iterating over the found <input> elements (as above):
Array.prototype.forEach.call(radioInputs, function(input) {

  // adding an event-listener for the 'change' event,
  // assigning the toggleElements() function to
  // handle this event:
  input.addEventListener('change', toggleElements);

  // triggering the 'change' event on page-load:
  input.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
});
```

```js
function toggleElements() {
  var check = this,
    refersTo = document.querySelectorAll('.' + check.dataset.refersto);

  if (refersTo && refersTo.length) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(refersTo, function(node) {
      if (check.checked && node.classList.contains(check.value)) {
        node.style.display = 'block';
      } else {
        node.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  }
}

var radioInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][data-refersto]'),
  changeEvent = new Event('change');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(radioInputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', toggleElements);
  input.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>I am a:</legend>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="A2" value="student" data-refersto="parentOrStudent" />Student</label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="A2" value="parent" data-refersto="parentOrStudent" />Parent</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="parentOrStudent student">
  <legend>If Student, High School Graduation Year:</legend>
  <select id="A3">
    <option disabled selected>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="parentOrStudent parent">
  <legend>If parent, some other pertinent question:</legend>
  <select id="A4">
    <option disabled selected>-- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

External [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/udm0uvod/1/), for experimentation.

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`Event()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Function.protype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; hopefully this answer was of some use to you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "name" attribute you can use the "Id" attribute and then you can easily get the value of checked radio button.
{

```
<input type="radio" id="rdStudent" value="student" name="A2"/>
<input type="radio" id="rdParent" value="parent" name="A2"/>
```

and then modify your jquery as given below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
(".studentq").hide();
$("#rdStudent").click(function(){
      if("#rdStudent").val()=="student")
       {
           $(".studentq").show(); 
       }
       else{
            $(".studentq").hide();
         }
});
});
```

In the same way you can check for second radio button also.